# Understanding some parts of the implementation proc mcmc

Tags: sas, mcmc

I am studying one implementation of `MCMC in SAS` here https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mcmc_examples13.htm

It implements

```
proc mcmc data=seeds outpost=postout seed=332786 nmc=20000;
   ods select PostSumInt;
   parms beta0 0 beta1 0 beta2 0 beta3 0 s2 1;
   prior s2 ~ igamma(0.01, s=0.01);
   prior beta: ~ general(0);
   w = beta0 + beta1*seed + beta2*extract + beta3*seed*extract;
   random delta ~ normal(w, var=s2) subject=ind;
   pi = logistic(delta);
   model r ~ binomial(n = n, p = pi);
run;
```

I fail to understand what are the purposes of the codeline `ods select PostSumInt;` and declaration `parms beta0 0 beta1 0 beta2 0 beta3 0 s2 1;` i.e. `beta0 0`? Are they starting values?

Also there seems to no definition of priors for `beta` coefficients, but I see there is one general definition `prior beta: ~ general(0);` How `beta` here is linked to `beta0, beta1` etc and what is `general(0)`?

I really appreciate for any clarification on above codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order of your questions:

- [`ods select`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/odsug/p1b72ff70v3obrn16aanp1r9q2bu.htm) will send whatever output that is named to the active ODS destination(s). It is the inverse of `ods exclude`, and by default all output will be shown unless it's been disabled earlier. In this case ODS will *only* receive the `PostSumInt` table. Each PROC has documentation on the output tables it produces, [here](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/statug/statug_mcmc_details118.htm) you'll see that `PostSumInt` is 'basic posterior statistics'. You can submit [`ods trace on`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/odsug/p1fpt3uuow90o3n155hs7bp1mo7f.htm) to get log feedback on ODS output.
- [`parms`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/statug/statug_mcmc_syntax12.htm) provides initializing values as you guessed. In addition parameters that are part of the same `parms` statement are updated together, so this can affect convergence efficiency.
- `beta:` is [SAS syntax](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lepg/p08ywlo51p6ezbn1lde9f0aphq6r.htm) for 'everything starting with `beta`' (specifically defined parameters here), so the prior statement indeed acts on all beta parameters. You can use such naming much more broadly, also in data steps etc., see the link.

It's not super straightforward to search, but the SAS documentation explains all of this.

Answer (score -1):

I will tell you only one thing, "ods", it stands for output delivery system which is used to get the output in a report style in a file, like pdf, rtf, Excel and text file. Okay?

Comment: Thanks. But does `PostSumInt ` mean exactly?